# Curl error SSL3_CHECK_CERT_AND_ALGORITHM: dh key too small

Tags: centos, openssl, ssl

When I run a get request from Curl to a web service I get the error `SSL3_CHECK_CERT_AND_ALGORITHM: dh key too small`. Server is on CentOS 6.6 and web service is a Java application (OpenJDK 1.7) running on Jetty 6. I know CentOS 6 is end-of-life and I am planning to upgrade OS but need this to work in the meantime.

There is another server that is also running on CentOS 6.6, have the same Java application (OpenJDK 1.7) and also running on Jetty 6 but does not have issue integrating with other sites.

When inspecting the output from the command `openssl s_client -connect 127.0.0.1:443 -tls1_2`, I noticed the temp key used and cipher suite is different between the two systems. The system that is not working is using DH keys for the temporary keys and cipher suite used is `AES128-SHA`. Whereas the system that is working is using `ECDH` as the temp key and the cipher suite used is `ECDH-RSA-AES128-SHA`.

When running `openssl ciphers -v`, the available ciphers are identical on both servers. For some reason the temp keys between the two systems differ and when testing the cipher suites, only a few works on one system compared to the other:

```
Testing AES256-SHA256...YES
Testing AES256-SHA...YES
...
Testing AES128-SHA256...YES
Testing AES128-SHA...YES
...
Testing RC4-SHA...YES
Testing RC4-MD5...YES
Testing RC4-MD5...YES
```

There were a lot of failures including the cipher that was working on the other system (ECDH-RSA-AES128-SHA.)

```
esting ECDH-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256...NO (sslv3 alert handshake failure)
Testing ECDH-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256...NO (sslv3 alert handshake failure)
Testing ECDH-RSA-AES128-SHA256...NO (sslv3 alert handshake failure)
Testing ECDH-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256...NO (sslv3 alert handshake failure)
Testing ECDH-RSA-AES128-SHA...NO (sslv3 alert handshake failure)
Testing ECDH-ECDSA-AES128-SHA...NO (sslv3 alert handshake failure)
```

I compared the config file `/etc/pki/tls/openssl.cnf` but did not find any differences. How can I get one server to use the same temp keys as the other?